# ّFragment coroutine error:Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-coroutines

Running this code in fragment i get  an error

```
 lifecycleScope.launch {
            dataBinding.wrongAnsweredText.text= WrongAnswerViewModel.getNotAnsweredQuestionsNum().toString()
        }
```

error:

```
Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing IO-burst jobs in main-thread causes locking the UI, because of the blocking nature of them. Try to call the database operations in `IO` context then touch the UI in the `Main` context like the following:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val notAnswered = WrongAnswerViewModel.getNotAnsweredQuestionsNum().toString()
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        dataBinding.wrongAnsweredText.text = notAnswered
    }
}
```